# Rails simple form grouped select custom label_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I'm using simple form and I have a grouped select input field:

```
<%= f.input :subcategory_id, label: false, collection: @subcategories.order(:alternative_name), :label_method => lambda { |item| "#{item.alternative_name}" }, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :child_subcategories, :include_blank => "--Select a category--"%>
```

In the `subcategory model` I have: `name: string, alternative_name:string` and in the `child-subcategory model` I have `name: string, alternative_name:string subcategory_id: integer`.

Everything works fine, the `child-subcategories` get grouped with the `subcategories`. And now in some parts of my app I would like to use the alternative names `column` instead of the name `column`. So I try this:

```
<%= f.input :subcategory_id, label: false, collection: @subcategories.order(:alternative_name), :label_method => lambda { |item| "#{item.alternative_name}" }, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :child_subcategories, :include_blank => "--Select a category--" %>
```

But with the above setup I only get the `child-subcategory` to change to the alternative_name `column`. How can I change both the `subcategory and child subcategory` to use the alternative_name `column` inside the grouped select??

Comment: You've posted the same line of code twice, is that deliberate?